# SharePoint permissions: Restrict users from deleting site elements

Tags: 2013, permissions, 2016, 2019

Can anyone please tell me how to prevent users from deleting site elements, i.e. letters, comments, tasks, etc.?

I am using SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a custom Permission Level that does not allow deleting. You would then grant all your users or groups this permission level. I [wrote a blog post](https://www.sharepointusecases.com/2008/06/document-libraries-specify-which-items-users-can-edit-delete-explained-part-1/) about that a while back, it is for SharePoint 2007, UI has changed, but the same principle still applies. To learn more check the [official documentation on permission levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).